# Discord.py Rewrite Cooldown Commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am using Discord.py Rewrite to make a Discord bot. I have a command called `work`, with the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="c!")
# on_ready command

@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    author_id = ctx.author.id
    currency_dict[author_id] += 50
    await ctx.send("You Gained 50 Coins")
# currency_dict is a dictionary that is already defined
```

Is there any way to make it so that the user can only use the command once every 30 seconds? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you would have to import `from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType`. This is what will help you with cooldowns. Below is both the `cooldown` check as well as the `max_concurrency` check you can use with this import.

```py
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
# BucketType can be BucketType.default, member, user, guild, role, or channel
@commands.cooldown(rate,per,BucketType) 
# Limit how often a command can be used, (num per, seconds, BucketType)

@commands.max_concurrency(number, per=BucketType.default, *, wait=False)
# Limit how many instances of the command can be running at the same time.
# Setting wait=True will queue up additional commands. False will raise MaxConcurrencyReached

# Checks can be stacked, and will Raise a CheckFailure if any check fails.
```

In your case, you would want to use `commands.cooldown(rate,per,BucketType)`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="c!")
# on_ready command

@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,30,commands.BucketType.user) # one command, every 30 seconds, per user
async def work(ctx):
    author_id = ctx.author.id
    currency_dict[author_id] += 50
    await ctx.send("You Gained 50 Coins")
# currency_dict is a dictionary that is already defined

# cooldown error-handling
@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f'This command is on cooldown, you can use it in {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds')
```

---

references:

- [docs: discord.ext.commands.cooldown](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)
- [StackOverflow: Command cooldown in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066170/command-cooldown-in-discord-py)
- [GitHub Gist: Built-in Checks for the commands extension of discord py](https://gist.github.com/Painezor/eb2519022cd2c907b56624105f94b190)