# how to make a different cooldown for each role in discord in py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I would like to know if its possible to make a code the

makes a cooldown
**per role**
like premium has no cooldown
and bronze has a 10 second
cooldown if so how can I do it ?
for commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command cooldown in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066170/command-cooldown-in-discord-py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py different cooldown per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581190/discord-py-different-cooldown-per-user)

Answer (score 0):

Why with commands? Wouldn't it be much easier to add and remove the roles with a command and control the cooldown via the server settings?

With a simple level-system this would be done very quickly.

(You could store the number of messages in a simple .json file and after a certain amount of messages add/remove the corresponding role.)

Comment: because i get spams in commands but like some people would have privilege's

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but, with the latest Discord Python library's dynamic cooldown, you can now do this:

```py
whitelist = {"Moderators", "Admins"}

def custom_cooldown(ctx):
    roles = {role.name for role in ctx.author.roles}
    if not whitelist.isdisjoint(roles):
        #if we're a special role, no cooldown assigned
        return None
    elif "SomeOtherPrivelagedRole" in roles:
        #some other privileged role
        discord.app_commands.Cooldown(1, 180)
    else:
        #everyone else
        return discord.app_commands.Cooldown(1, 300)

@bot.command(name='test')
@commands.dynamic_cooldown(custom_cooldown, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, *args):
    #your code here
    pass
```

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.dynamic_cooldown) for more info.